# how to check if a file is git ignored

Tags: git

I have two css files. One is GIT ignored and other is not.

I want to confirm which one is ignored and which one is not.

I can use following command to check if files are ignored.

git status --ignored

How to check for a specific file?

Comment: If git ignored, the file should not even show in a `git status`

Answer (score 23):

`git check-ignore <filename>`

From https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore

`git-check-ignore` - Debug gitignore / exclude files

`-v` shows specific line and file that make git to ignore the file.

```
$ git check-ignore -v build
C:/Users/username/gitignore:23:**/build*       build
```